# Problems with react-native-firebase installation

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am trying to get firebase up and running multiple times but I keep running into problems. I follow all instructions [here:](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/kowop2-244da/overview) but whenever I get to the step of adding

@import Firebase;
and 
[FIRApp configure];

to my appdelegate class, things go wrong and when running 'react-native run-ios' it says:

Successfully launched the app on the simulator
But the simulator stays empty.

This is my appdelegate class:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
@import Firebase;

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"kowop2"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [FIRApp configure];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

I also tried to replace
 `@import Firebase;` 
with

```
#import <Firebase.h>
```

But no success.

I have the google plist file in my ios folder. This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "kowop2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.3.4",
    "raysk-vali": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.2.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.2.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.8.2",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.8.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

And this is my podfile

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'kowop2' do
  # Pods for kowop2
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'

  target 'kowop2Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end

target 'kowop2-tvOS' do
  # Pods for kowop2-tvOS

  target 'kowop2-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Tim

Answer (score -1):

I see that you implement in `appDelegate.m` `react-native-firebase` the **v5** way, but in the package.json you have installed **v6**,

In v6 you implement like this:
add in imports : `#import <Firebase.h>`
and in Within the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method add:

```
if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
      [FIRApp configure];
    }
```

see the [docs](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/quick-start/ios-firebase-credentials)